# SQL Server 2005 user prioritization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I currently have a SQL Server 2005 database that is accessed by multiple users.  Is it possible to have SQL give processing priority to specific users based on their login names?  ie, if Alice and Bob are both running queries simultaneously, I want to ensure that Bob is given priority over Alice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 has a new feature called Resource Governor that will do what you are asking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx

You are using SQL 2005 which does not have this ability.

Comment: Thanks!  Yet another reason to upgrade.